# pgpass file that uses variables?

Tags: psql

I'm working on a docker image that connects to postgres using psql.

My entrypoint:

```
psql analytics \
  --host=${INPUT_HOST} \
  --username=analytics \
  --port=32648
```

If I run this I'm prompted for a password, I enter it and am able to connect. Great.

But if I try to make the password entry automatic I get an error:

```
psql analytics \
  --host=${INPUT_HOST} \
  --username=analytics \
  --port=32648 \
  --password=${INPUT_PASSWORD}
```

> /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/psql: option '--password' doesn't allow an argument
> Try "psql --help" for more information.

I found some docs on using .pgpass and this file which is to be added to a users home directory takes the form:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Now I'm going to have to do something like:

```
${INPUT_HOST}:5432:analytics:analytics:${INPUT_PASSWORD}
```

Then envsubst or sed on this file before adding to the image.

Open ended question, is there a better/more convenient way? `${INPUT_PASSWORD}` comes from a docker secret. Is there anyway I can pass a password to my call to psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a connection string:

```sh
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}' dbname=analytics host='${INPUT_HOST}' user=analytics port=32648"
```